# Want to display Map but no current position. What's needed?

Tags: android, android-mapview

In my actual project I need to draw a MapView with a given running/walking/cycling path on top of it.

I don't need the current position so I added an overlay just for the path (no MyLocationOverlay). The path is painted but I don't see the Map in the emulator - only the grey tiles. The apiKey is set in the layout (MapView) and INTERNET permission is set in the Manifest.

So I'm wondering if I need more. Is it the emulator simply not working well (I do have 3G and 2 bars in the emulator) or do I need something else? Do I need to build an additional overlay or add additional permissions (xxxLOCATION) to the Manifest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're describing what what I've only seen when I've got the map key wrong. Did you generate it yourself? If you're running the unsigned .apk in the emulator you should be [following these steps](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html#getdebugfingerprint).

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. I went back and double-checked the Maps Debug Key. I got a new one and it is working now. The old debug key is working successful in another project. Hmm, this time I got a new key. I'm pretty sure that I checked this key when I started the current project and I'm pretty sure that I got the same key back from Google. Hmm, mystery. However, thanks a lot. Checking the key again was the last thing I would have done.